# Java 8 Stream Reduce of Arbitrary Class Type

Tags: java, java-8

Okay, this is NOT a homework question, this is a "me getting with the Java 8 program and hoping to eventually pass the certification exam" question.

I'm trying to figure out the reduce() method, in terms of reducing a List of an arbitary class (not the String or Integer most example code I see uses) to a single member of my code.

```
package playground;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

public static class MyClass {

    private int accumulator = 0;

    public MyClass() {

    }

    public MyClass(int initValue) {
        this.accumulator = initValue;
    }

    public int getAccumulator() {
        return accumulator;
    }

    public void setAccumulator(int accumulator) {
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
    }


}

public static void main(String... args) {

    MyClass mc1 = new MyClass(6);
    MyClass mc2 = new MyClass(8);
    MyClass mc3 = new MyClass(3);

    List<MyClass> myList = Arrays.asList(mc1, mc2, mc3);
    MyClass finalClass = myList.stream().reduce(new MyClass(0), 
        // need the correct lambda function here
    );


}
```

}

Comment: You would need something which would dictate how two `MyClass` instances are combined.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for help with. Lambda functions are new to me and I'm trying to learn to use them.

Comment: `(m1, m2) -> new MyClass(m1.getAccumulator() + m2.getAccumulator())`

Comment: Since your class seems to be intentionally mutable, using `.collect(MyClass::new, (c, e) -> c.setAccumulator(c.getAccumulator() + e.getAccumulator()), (c1, c2) -> c1.setAccumulator(c1.getAccumulator() + c2.getAccumulator()) );` is potentially more efficient. See [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction)

Comment: Possibly, but JynXXedRabbitFoot's response was a bit more understandable.

Comment: Sure, but since this is for educational purpose, it’s worth learning the difference between Reduction and Mutable Reduction and their pros and cons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something to the effect of:

```
MyClass finalClass = myList.stream()
    .reduce((a, b) -> new MyClass(a.accumulator + b.accumulator))
    .orElse(new MyClass(0));
```

This takes 2 inputs, which have to be surrounded by parentheses, and reduces them to one output. Note this returns an `Optional`.

An easy way to handle this is with orElse which is equivalent to:

```
if(myList.size() == 0){
    return new MyClass(0);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that returns an Optional<MyClass> but is otherwise good. I was looking at the other signatures with BiFunction<U, ? super T> and BinaryOperator<U> and couldn't really figure it out.

Comment: @Jason note the `orElse` `Stream` operation after the `reduce`, this handles the optional gracefully. You will only fall through to the `orElse` if the original `List` is empty. This gives it a return type of `MyClass`.

Comment: Right, I see that. Unfortunately, I waited to long and couldn't edit my original comment.

Comment: @Jason No worries, does this clear up your understanding?

Comment: Not completely, but it does for that use case. I'm still trying to figure out how to use the more complex versions of reduce(). I'll keep at it.